# Change number of servings on click (React Hooks - API)

Tags: json, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I'm working on a recipe site using API from a third party and want to change the **number of servings** (*which is output from the API data*) when clicking the + & - button. I tried assigning the output serving amount `<Servings>{recipe.servings}</Servings>` in a variable and useState to update it but it kept showing errors. I would appreciate any help (**preferably using react Hooks**). Thanks :)

Here is my code:

```js
const id = 716429;
const apiURL = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${id}/information`;
const apiKey = "34ac49879bd04719b7a984caaa4006b4";
const imgURL = `https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_100x100/`;

const {
    data: recipe,
    error,
    isLoading,
  } = useFetch(apiURL + "?apiKey=" + apiKey);
  
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(true);

const handleChange = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
  };
```

```js
return (
    <Section>
      <h2>Ingredients</h2>
      <ServingsandUnits>
        {recipe && (
          <ServingsIncrementer>
            <p>Servings: </p>
            <Minus />
            <Servings>{recipe.servings}</Servings>
            <Plus />
          </ServingsIncrementer>
        )}

        <ButtonGroup>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="metric"
            name="unit"
            checked={isChecked}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="male">Metric</label>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </ServingsandUnits>
     </Section> 
};
```

My custom hook is called useFetch:

```js
const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortCont = new AbortController();

    fetch(url, { signal: abortCont.signal })
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          // error coming back from server
          throw Error("Could not fetch the data for that resource");
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setData(data);
        setError(null);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.name === "AbortError") {
          console.log("Fetch aborted");
        } else {
          // auto catches network / connection error
          setIsLoading(false);
          setError(err.message);
        }
      });

    return () => {
      abortCont.abort();
    };
  }, [url]);
  return { data, isLoading, error };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Comment: So you want that whenver + or - is clicked , recipes.serving value change accordingly?

Comment: Yes. Exactly!!!